# Tesseract installation in windows

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am currently working on optimal character recognition project using python 2.7,open computer vision in windows.To accomplish this task i came to know that it can be done by using tesseract (software).But, it cannot be installed on windows. I searched a lot but i could not get the solution. Can any one  tell me is there any way of installing it  on windows ?or can it be done without using it?

Comment: Have you searched on [GitHub](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract)?

Answer (score 33):

Simple  steps for tesseract  installation in windows.

1. Download tesseract exe from https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki.
2. Install this exe in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR`
3. Open virtual machine command prompt in windows or anaconda prompt.
4. Run `pip install pytesseract`
5. To test if tesseract  is installed type in python prompt:

   import pytesseract

   print(pytesseract)

Comment: I had to install pytesseract instead

Comment: @Aashish Raina Please change `pip install  tesseract` to `pip install pytesseract`. `tesseract` is some other unrelated package.

Answer (score 15):

To accomplish OCR with Python on Windows, you will need Python and OpenCV which you already have, as well as Tesseract and the [Pytesseract](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/) Python package.

To install Tesseract OCR for Windows:

1. Run the [installer](https://digi.bib.uni-mannheim.de/tesseract/)(find 2021) from UB Mannheim
2. Configure your installation (choose installation path and language data to include)
3. Add Tesseract OCR to your environment variables

To install and use Pytesseract on Windows:

1. Simply run `pip install pytesseract`
2. You will also need to install [Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) with `pip install Pillow` to use Pytesseract. Import it in your Python document like so `from PIL import Image`.
3. You will need to add the following line in your code in order to be able to call pytesseract on your machine: `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'`

I've given a detailed walkthrough of how to install Tesseract OCR for Windows [here](https://codetoprosper.com/tesseract-ocr-for-windows/) if you would like further guidance.

Comment: Can't you just add this path to PATH variable?

Comment: I thought this as well, but when I tried to execute the pytesseract script without the additional line of code to include the path, it didn't work despite having added the path to the PATH variable as you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

UB Mannheim provide pre-built binaries for the latest versions of `tesseract`.

From [`tesseract` Github wiki](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki).

> ### Windows
>
> An unofficial installer for windows for Tesseract 3.05-dev and
>   Tesseract 4.00-dev is available from [Tesseract at UB
>   Mannheim](https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki). This
>   includes the training tools.
>
> ...
>
> To access tesseract-OCR from any location you may have to add the
>   directory where the tesseract-OCR binaries are located to the Path
>   variables, probably `C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR`.