# pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-tesseract

i created a script in python with libraries such as pyautogui,pytesseract
then, i've converted the script into an .exe file using auto py to exe and everything ran fine on my PC, the problem is when i sent the file to my friends they experienced an error that said pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError

Here is my code:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import pyautogui
import os


pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = \
    r'C:\Users\iunth\AppData\Local\Programs\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'

acceptImage = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(599,587,733,198))
acceptWord = pytesseract.image_to_string(acceptImage)

while acceptWord != 'ACCEPT!':
    acceptImage = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(599,587,733,198))
    acceptWord = pytesseract.image_to_string(acceptImage)
    print("Waiting for queue pop...")
    #print(acceptWord)
    if 'ACCEPT!' in acceptWord:
        accept = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('accept.jpg',confidence=0.8)
        print(acceptWord)
        pyautogui.moveTo(accept)
        pyautogui.click()
        break
```

i've installed pytesseract with vcpkg so i can export it as .exe and worked fine on my PC
how do i fix this?

Comment: I believe this is because the pytesseract package is not enough on its own; you also need the underlying Tesseract binary package, which your friend does not have.  Or perhaps they do have it, but in a location where your exe can't find it.

Comment: Check / set the system environment variable with the path to you /bin tesseract.exe. In addition there is also a possibility to insert the search path in your python script.

Comment: Perhaps this thread could be helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46140485/tesseract-installation-in-windows

Comment: pytesseract is already installed on my machine, i want it to run on other PC's without them needing to have pytesseract installed, how do i export it with the .exe along with other packages that are already exported on their own?